# How to sort list of list on the basis of two elements, in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, sublist

I have a=[[1,2],[2,1],[3,2],[5,1],[4,1]]

I want to get the result sorted list as

[[2,1],[4,1],[5,1],[1,2],[3,2]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this by doing following-
a.sort(key=lambda tup:tup[0])
    
a.sort(key=lambda tup:tup[1])